# Which one has higher square sum error using K-means?

Tags: clustering, k-means

I have trouble in coming out with a straightforward way to know which one is better in K-means when clustering considering SSE(squared sum error). Thanks.

[image: p1]

[image: p2]

Comment: Can you explain the pictures - what do the red +'s represent?

Comment: The centroid after applying the K-means.

Comment: I think there may be some problem with the images because in K-means , the center is the mean of the data points in the cluster and hence the centers should fall between the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Either can be better

This depends on the scales of your axes.

If x is [0;1] and y is [0;100000] then the upper is better.

If x is [0;100000] and y is [0;1] then the lower is better.

Unfortunately, k-means is *very* sensitive to scale.

Answer (score 1):

Kmeans has many local minima (cluster results) and it is possible that certain local minima have higher or lower or equal Loss with others.

In your picture, it is possible in all three ways. You can just calculate the loss the check.

In sum, from the figure, it is not easy to tell. From theory, it is possible to have larger, smaller or equal loss values.